# probability problem

Tags: probability-theory

the probability that a man who is 85 yrs old will die before attaining the age of 90 is 1/3. Four persons A1,A2,A3, and A2 are 85 yrs old. The probability that A1 will die before attaining the age 90 and will  be the first one to die is

Comment: This is a less routine question than most basic probability questions. It does not yield immediately to mechanical manipulation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I suspect that this question was closed not because it is too localised, but rather because it is considered bad form to copy and paste a question from wherever you found it. People like to know where a question came from, and what the OP has tried. On the other hand, I think it is bad form to close a question without giving the OP a clue as to why it has been closed. In fact, I think that doing so is downright rude. I am therefore voting to re-open. Out of spite.

Comment: @user1729: The question (apart from being more interesting than many) seems no more or less quoted than many others. If there were clear criteria for closure in such cases, and they were applied fairly systematically, then I would understand (though perhaps not approve).

Comment: @AndréNicolas What would you understand?

Comment: @user1729: I would understand *why* the closure. But when this is done very sporadically, when it is done it appears arbitrary.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I agree entirely! Although, as I said in my earlier comment, it bugs me most when people do not bother to take the time to give the OP some feedback on how to improve their question.

Comment: @André I agree wholeheartedly. I cast the final reopen vote. One can quickly find improperly closed questions from the [10K tools](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools) and the review queues. Be sure to click the triangle on "recently closed" to see the full list.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [MSE quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: This question was just reopened and is now about to be closed again.  Which is retarded.

Comment: @Noah: No. It doesn’t match the standards of **some** MSE users. As anyone reading the comments can see, other users disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Assume independence. Beside A_1, there could be $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$ people who die before age $90$.

The probability that A1 dies and the others don't is $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3$. If this happens, then A1 is sure to be first.

The probability that A1 and exactly one other person dies before $90$ is $\binom{3}{1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2$. If this happens, then A1 is first with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

The probability that A1 and exactly two other people die before $90$ is $\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$. If this happens, then A1 is first with probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

The probability that everybody dies before $90$ is $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4$. If this happens, then A1 is first with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.

Add the numbers obtained for the $4$ cases to find the probability.

Comment: The way I read the question, "first to die" simply happens in 3! cases (the orders in which the other three people die) out of 4! cases (all the possible arrangements of the orders of death), which means that the person has a 1/4 chance of being the first to die, regardless of the age of anyone when they die. Of course this is also what we expect if we select the order of deaths by drawing names out of a hat.

Answer (score 2):

A1 can be the first to die:  if dies and is the only one who does, probability $=\frac 13\cdot (\frac 23)^3$,  or if he is one of two who die and he is first, probability $(\frac 13)^2(\frac 23)^2 \frac 12$, or (just keep going)